# How to connect AWS node with Metamask?

Tags: metamask, json-rpc, geth-debugging, rpc, aws

Sorry its really primitive and silly question but I'm very low on information about this area but from the things I've heard and I've seen I managed to create a node from "https://eu-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/managedblockchain/" here.
Now I have this node here

[image]

I've tried adding http endpoint as a network to metamask but it didn't work.
I've tried adding the node port number at the end of the http endpoint and it didn't work either.
I'm stuck, can anyone help me how can I add this as a MM node?

Answer (score 1):

Geth (GoEthereum) full nodes on Amazon Managed Blockchain for testnets and mainnet are secured by [Sigv4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) to prevent unauthorized use of your node, therefore you must append the appropriate Sigv4 signature to requests to the endpoints for the node.

In order to connect MetaMask to the node via an endpoint, you can create a proxy using AWS services such as API Gateway and AWS Lambda that will accept requests from MetaMask and append the Sigv4 signature to those requests and forward them to your node(s) in Amazon Managed Blockchain. This effectively provides a public endpoint from API Gateway that you can use with MetaMask as the custom RPC URL. Please note that this will open your node up to the public, so anyone with knowledge of that API Gateway endpoint will be able to send requests to the node.

For client applications, there are also helper libraries available to manage Web3 providers with Sigv4, e.g. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-web3-http-provider

**!! Be mindful about protecting your AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key, as anyone who has your access keys has the same level of access to your AWS resources that you do.**